# How (the heck) can thrusters alone stabilize New Horizons well enough to take high magnification 30 second long exposures in order to see +21 m objs?

Tags: attitude, mission-design, photography, new-horizons, attitude-determination-and-control

Wikipedia's [Long Range Reconnaissance Imager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Range_Reconnaissance_Imager#Operations) says that LORRI is a:

> ...telescope aboard the New Horizons spacecraft for imaging. LORRI has been used to image Jupiter, its moons, Pluto and its moons, and Arrokoth since its launch in 2006. LORRI is a reflecting telescope of Ritchey-Chrétien design, and it has a main mirror diameter of 20.8 cm (8.2 inches) across. LORRI has a narrow field of view, less than a third of a degree. Images are taken with a CCD capturing data with 1024 × 1024 pixels. LORRI is a telescopic panchromatic camera integrated with the New Horizons spacecraft, and it is one of seven major science instruments on the probe. **LORRI does not have any moving parts and is pointed by moving the entire New Horizons spacecraft.**

Later in [design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Range_Reconnaissance_Imager#Specifications) it says:

> The design can take images at very low light levels required for the mission, including light levels 1/900 those of Earth when it is at Pluto.[4] For the Arrokoth encounter the longest exposure time (up to ten seconds for the Pluto flyby) was increased. **This was accomplished after the Pluto flyby by the team, to support taking images in even lower light levels.**
>
> **After the Pluto flyby, exposure times of at least 30 seconds were made possible, which was also useful for taking reconnaissance images and enabling imaging down to a magnitude of 21.**
>
> LORRI is pointed by moving the entire spacecraft, which limits the exposure time. **The spacecraft does not have reaction wheels and is stabilized by thrusters.**

Seeing a +21 magnitude star with a 20.8 cm telescope will require a long exposure time as mentioned. I am surprised that thrusters alone can stabilize this spacecraft and therefore this telescope so well without the use of any other attitude control system.

Unlike the push-broom cameras popular on some deep space spacecraft that use slow spacecraft rotation to scan their 1D CDD across a field for imaging purposes, LORRI is a "normal" 2D CCD camera and so requires steady pointing during an exposure.

**Question:** How (the heck) can thrusters alone stabilize New Horizons well enough to take high magnification 30 second long exposures in order to see +21 mag. objects?

Are there any special tricks to this? Perhaps firing opposite thrusters for very slightly different times rather than trying to fire only one for a very short time? Are there any other sources of torque that are used to fine-null any rotation during the up to 30 second long exposures?

From Wikipedia's [New Horizons; Propulsion and attitude control] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons):

> There are 16 thrusters on New Horizons: four 4.4 N (1.0 lbf) and **twelve 0.9 N** (0.2 lbf) plumbed into redundant branches. The larger thrusters are used primarily for trajectory corrections, and the small ones ... are used primarily for attitude control.

Comment: What would be an acceptable angular velocity that can be tolerated to take a picture with exposure time of 30s?

Comment: Given that the control thrusters are only 0.9N (some sources cite 0.8N), and can fire for as short a duration as 5 *milli* seconds (total impulse of 5mNsec ! ), they are suitable for some *ludicrously* fine adjustments.

Comment: @AJN Astrometry like the parallax measurements can be done to a few percent of 1 pixel, but those are short exposures for bright, nearby stars. In fact [Betelgeuse is too bright for a parallax measurement!](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39427/7982) For normal imaging of dim asteroids (which is that the +21 mag would likely be for) ~1 pixel might be sufficient, though if it's going to aim for one you'd want as much astrometric precision as you can get I suppose.

Comment: If the pixel referred angular spread (over 30s duration) can be converted to spacecraft referred angular shift, a back of the envelope calculation can be made based on the thruster level and firing duration.

Comment: @AJN and so it sounds like an answer seems possible. But it will have to be fact-based and supported with sources.

Comment: Modern thrusters have fine controls. While the GNC flight control software typically runs at a slowish rate, it commands the attitude control thrusters to fire at a fractional on-time, typically in integral increments of the thruster's minimum on-time.

Comment: http://seitzman.gatech.edu/classes/ae6450/MR-103H_Hydrazine_Thruster_New_Horizons.pdf and [The thrusters are operated in pulse mode with a pulse length of 5 milliseconds to achieve the desired control precision with the Inertial Measurement Units used as the fine rate control sensors.](https://spaceflight101.com/newhorizons/spacecraft-overview/) and [Table II gives the measured average rate change from 5­ms pulse](https://www.boulder.swri.edu/pkb/ssr/ssr-fountain.pdf) of between 15 and 25  μrad/s.

Comment: @Vince49 Are you certain that there are no "folks as APL or SSG" here already? Or that nobody here knows anybody there, or has any first-hand information from the mission themselves? Space SE has thousands of users that visit regularly. Let's wait and see what happens before deciding "nobody can answer".

Comment: @uhoh, I know some of the people who built LORRI, but I was not directly involved with that instrument.  Did you remove the data that was in my comment that led to my conclusion? 'Away for a while now for real.  'Will check back later.

Comment: @Vince49 cool! It's a totally different mission but if you know someone who knows someone who knows someone who might know the answer to [Why is TESS' high gain antenna made of undulating BLACK fabric rather than metal?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21768) please call their attention to it. It's a real mystery to me!

Comment: I'm reposting a comment where I said  "I don't think a fact-based answer in possible (w/o talking to folks as APL or SSG)".   Somehow the facts that I based that conclusion on were lost.  They are: the IFOV (Instantaneous Field of View) of one pixel of the LORRI imager is 4.94 µrad, the drift rate of the spacecraft in Observing Mode is ±34 µrad/sec, and the stored drift knowledge resolution is 7.5 µrad/sec.  For a maximum spatial resolution image integrated over 30 sec, the total drift would need to be small relative to 4.94 µrad.  Other than blind luck, I don't see how it could be done.

Comment: @uhoh TESS was designed, built, and operated by Northrop-Grumman.  I don't know anyone there.

Comment: @Vince49 even if there was drift, couldn't one just do image stacking of 60 0.5s exposures instead of a single 30s exposure ?

Comment: @AJN [space telescopes often do that](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/176710) for higher dynamic range, I'm not sure LORRI had the ability to rapid buffer so many images, but if it did then that solves that!

Comment: @AJN I believe that is a realistic possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LORRI Wikipedia article cites the following two sources for this:

- [LONG-RANGE RECONNAISSANCE IMAGER ON NEW HORIZONS, Cheng et al. (2008)](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0709/0709.4278.pdf)
- [Emily Lakdawalla Planetary Society article](https://www.planetary.org/articles/0124-new-horizons-prepares-for-2014mu69)

The latter being the likely origin:

> The New Horizons team has now enabled LORRI to take images with exposure times of 30 seconds. [...]. Before, the dimmest objects they could reliably detect were at about a visual magnitude of 20, but the longer exposure pushes that down to 21.

[LONG-RANGE RECONNAISSANCE IMAGER ON NEW HORIZONS, Cheng et al. (2008)](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0709/0709.4278.pdf) says:

> LORRI has a **4×4 pixel binning mode**, for which its **limiting magnitude requirement** is **V>17 in a single exposure of 9.9s**. This 4×4 pixel-binning mode will be used to search for the target KBO and to perform optical navigation on approach. A ***special* spacecraft guidance mode** is available for the KBO search in which **the spacecraft will hold the target within the 4×4 pixel pointing tolerance for 10 second exposures**. [emphasis added]

- [article describing pixel binning](https://hamamatsu.magnet.fsu.edu/articles/binning.html#:%7E:text=Pixel%20binning%20is%20a%20clocking,frame%20rate%20of%20digital%20cameras.&text=Dynamic%20range%20of%20a%20CCD%20is%20directly%20proportional%20to%20the%20well%20depth.)

The paper later mentions:

> In general, exposures of 50 to 200 milliseconds are typical for LORRI, although the **maximum exposure time is 29.9 seconds**. [emphasis added]

So perhaps the capability was always there? Just now it has been "enabled", i.e., *turned on*?

Either way, the same paper also gives the pixel field-of-view (IFOV) as 4.94 micro radians (vertically/horizontally, not diagonally). This means the 4x4 binned 'super-pixel' has an IFOV of **~20 micro radians**. The regular/normal 3-axis attitude control system specifications are (per [The New Horizons Spacecraft, Fountain et al.](https://www.boulder.swri.edu/pkb/ssr/ssr-fountain.pdf)):

> The control algorithms must **maintain the spacecraft attitude to within ±24 µrad (3σ)** and the spacecraft rotational rate to within ±34 µrad/s (3σ). [emphasis added]

This looks something like this:

[image: Pixel diagram]

Where the grid represents the individual pixels, the red square the 4x4 binned pixel, and the blue circles the normal (3-axis) allowable spacecraft pointing error.

This is evidently not good enough for imaging dim objects, hence the aforementioned special mode, which I suspect is just lowering the dead bands in the attitude controller. However, there is also problems with *too* accurate a spacecraft attitude; another point of note from [Cheng et al.](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0709/0709.4278.pdf):

> For optical navigation, LORRI is required to be able to image a **star of visual magnitude V=11.5** at SNR>7 in a **single 100 ms exposure**, with **full width at half maximum (FWHM) >1 pixel**. It is ***not desirable for too great a fraction of the energy from a point source to be imaged onto a single pixel***, because stellar images become too undersampled. [emphasis added]

(*for what its worth the section in between these quotes is the first quoted passage from Cheng et al. above*)

> At **40 AU** from the Sun, LORRI is predicted to be able to detect a **50 km diameter** object, of **albedo 0.04** and at phase angle 25°, from a distance of **0.35 AU**, more than 40 days before the object would be encountered. [emphasis added]

I do not know if/how the undersampling concern applies in the 4x4 pixel binning mode, but the test [Kuiper Belt Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Kuiper_belt_object) described in the latter quote has an angular diameter of ~1 micro radian, less than a single pixel:

[image: test KBO size]

***So how is the increase in pointing accuracy only now achieved?***

I think it comes from, somewhat counter-intuitively, the ***reduced*** efficiency of the propulsion system.

New Horizons uses a blowdown propulsion system which is characterized by a decrease in feed/tank pressure as propellant is used, seen in figure 3 from [THE USE OF THE AEROJET MR-103H THRUSTER ON THE NEW HORIZONS MISSION TO PLUTO, Stratton (2004)](http://seitzman.gatech.edu/classes/ae6450/MR-103H_Hydrazine_Thruster_New_Horizons.pdf) (thanks comment section):

[image: New Horizons blowdown pressure]

This corresponds to a decrease in the minimum impulse bit ([Figure 6, Stratton (2004)](http://seitzman.gatech.edu/classes/ae6450/MR-103H_Hydrazine_Thruster_New_Horizons.pdf)):

[image: minimum impulse bit]

And with reference to the angular velocity change from a single thruster pair pulse (min impulse bit), [Cheng et al.](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0709/0709.4278.pdf) says (thanks comments):

> These numbers improve (decrease) as the feed pressure of the spacecraft propulsion system decreases.

Finally, the [Planetary Society article](https://www.planetary.org/articles/0124-new-horizons-prepares-for-2014mu69) (from Jan 2018) indicates fuel levels:

> Of the 75 kilograms of propellant that they launched with, 21 kilograms remain. Another 12 or so will be spent completing the extended mission, leaving about 9 for a possible second mission extension.

**Answer:**

The ~30 % decrease in minimum impulse bit (from propellant use) lowers the spacecraft's minimum angular velocity change to a level that permits 30 second exposures in the "special spacecraft guidance mode" combined w/ 4x4 pixel binning.

Comment: Fascinating in-depth answer! `+n!` We'll have to ask separately about what exactly is the "special spacecraft guidance mode".